# Why wasn't there an OP for Shinobu Time?

Tags: monogatari-series, maaya-sakamoto

Each of the arcs of the *Monogatari* series through the end of *Second Season* (Hitagi Crab, Mayoi Snail, ..., Hitagi End) has had an OP theme sung by the arc's heroine<sup>1</sup>, save for Shinobu Time (i.e. Onimonogatari), which did not have an OP theme at all.

What gives? Shinobu's voice actress is Maaya Sakamoto, who is probably the most talented singer out of the entire Monogatari cast! Why didn't she sing an OP for Shinobu's arc?

---

<sup>1</sup> Well, the OP for Hitagi End (Koimonogatari) was sung by both Kaiki and Senjougahara, but I think we can agree that they were both the heroines of that arc.

Comment: Just for more info, Beside being voice actress and singer, Maaya Sakamoto also songwriter and actress.

Comment: Kaiki as Heroine. I like the idea.

Answer (score 12):

Well, it turns out that Maaya Sakamoto doesn't like mixing her career as a singer with her career as a voice actress, as she pointed out in [an interview with director Masaaki Oosumi](http://osumi.air-nifty.com/blog/2008/02/vol3_b9ea.html)<sup>1</sup>:

> **Sakamoto:** [laughter] [...] I'm old-fashioned - I don't want my work as a voice actress to get mixed up with my singing.
>
> —What exactly do you mean by that?
>
> **Sakamoto:** To me, my job as a singer is not so much a job, as it is a way of expressing myself - which is why I should write my own lyrics and sing under my own name. That's why, as a rule, I don't sing character songs.

Of course, all the OP songs for the *Monogatari* series are character songs in the usual sense (e.g. Nadeko, rather than Kana Hanazawa, is [listed as the singer for "Mousou Express"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22e5s.jpg)), and so it makes sense that Maaya Sakamoto wouldn't sing an OP for Shinobu's arc.

Note that there *are* shows for which Maaya Sakamoto has both sung an OP/ED and voice-acted a character, e.g. *RahXephon* - but in these cases, it appears that she is credited as herself, rather than as her character. (This is certainly the case for *RahXephon*'s OP "Hemisphere"; I imagine it is also the case for the other anime in which this occurs, but I haven't checked.)

---

All that said, the Blu-ray version of *Second Season* does, in fact, have a minute-long opening segment for Shinobu Time. But it's set to the song ["white lies"](http://vgmdb.net/album/42417), which is not sung by Maaya Sakamoto - it's a non-vocal piece, aside from some choral chanting. (Though I should like to mention that it's an incredible song in its own right, especially if you listen to the full 3'23" version.)

---

<sup>1</sup> To find the bit I've translated here, Ctrl+F for *私も古い考え方*.

Answer (score -1):

In kizumonogatari we got a french song (Etoile Et Toi) at the end credits which was sung by an adult and later on by a child (3rd movie), which gives us the overall journey of Kiss-shot (shinobu) from shrinking into a child and growing back into a fully grown adult (especially the melons).

Also, it is said that she came from a foreign country (but was not stated which country it was), and I guess that explains why her hair is blond in the first place. She also loves eating donuts-- I mean french people love pastries, but dunno lol.

Overall, even though we didn't get a song sung by her VA, it is still nice that we got a wonderful french song that made kizumonogatari so beautiful. I guess shinobu herself can't sing japanese that's why she sung in french. ;-;